# Access Database design when changing course fee after certain period of time

Tags: database, ms-access

I have three tables:

### student

id (pk)
name

### course

id (pk)
course_name
course_duration
course_fee

### student_course

student_course_id (pk)
student_id (fk)
course_id (fk)

If after a certain period of time course fee changes then how can I maintain the record of student having previous course fee?

Comment: [My answer to a similar question might help.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15506769/577417)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically you copy it into the enrolments table (student_course). This supposes that the price will not change after the registration.

Comment: that means i have to add a column name called course_fee in student_course table.. so that if course_fee changes in course table it wont affect previous record

Comment: ok thank u very much... what if i want to keep all the history of course fee that been changed in certain period of time without affecting other record..

Comment: @AshishPoudel the link I have provided above shows you how to do that.

Comment: @BenjaminGale i have recreated the design the above links shows my design plz say me if it is correct or not. the link is below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwIgqugOah3-UXh1OFZ5SU1pMkk/edit?usp=sharing